# In a proportional odds model, when two adjacent categories are pooled together, the estimated parameters (slopes) are changing, even they shouldn't

Tags: ordered-logit

In several articles I've red that when using proportional odds (PO, or cumulative logit) model  it is natural to collapse adjacent categories of outcome since the slope parameter remains unchanged. Currently, I'm utilizing the `clm()` function in `R` with the following syntax: `clm <- clm(response ~ time + Group, data = DatasetLong)`. My response variable comprises four levels: 0, 1, 2, and 3. Upon inspecting the model summary, I observe the following output:

```
formula: response ~ time + Group
data:    DatasetLong

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
time     0.1268     0.0432    2.94   0.0033 ** 
Group4   0.0923     0.2746    0.34   0.7369    
Group5   1.3196     0.2858    4.62  3.9e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
0|1    0.926      0.330    2.80
1|2    2.560      0.362    7.07
2|3    6.007      0.677    8.87
(197 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Then I have tried to collapse level 0 and 1 `(DatasetLong$response2 <- recode_factor(DatasetLong$response, "0"="1")` and fit the same model: `clm2 <- clm(response2 ~ time + Group, data=DatasetLong)`, where response2 now has only 3 levels:1,2,3. According to "invariant under collapsability" property I would assume the same estimates for time, Group4 and Group5. However, my output for `summary(clm2)` is:

```
summary(clm2)
formula: response2 ~ time + Group
data:    DatasetLong

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
time     0.0597     0.0550    1.09  0.27774    
Group4  -0.0217     0.4029   -0.05  0.95712    
Group5   1.3584     0.3595    3.78  0.00016 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2    2.117      0.452    4.69
2|3    5.569      0.730    7.62
(197 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

The estimates for time, Group4 and Group5 completely different. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: There is no reason for them to be the same.  I think you are confusing sample estimates with population truths under a proportional hazards model.  Under PO the population parameters should behave as you’ve indicated.  And place state which R package the fitting function comes from.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm still unclear on how to interpret the statement that 'collapsing adjacent categories of outcome would not change the estimated parameters' in the case of the proportional odds model (unlike the continuation ratio model). I have reviewed the article (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243102781_Small_Samples_and_Ordered_Logistic_Regression), and in Table 2, it appears that the estimates remain consistent whether the categories are collapsed or not. I am utilizing the clm function from the ordinal package for my analysis.

Comment: @Bettina unfortunately, the paper is paywalled and it's hard to tell the context in which they make that claim. Claims in abstracts are nuanced and require a full view to know the context. At best, it may be the case that, when the proportional odds assumption holds, the estimates are *expected* to be unchanged. In reality, the inference is probably less efficient.

Comment: Just because the coefficient estimates are slightly different, doesn't mean the population values are, as Frank mentioned. You can formally test this in several ways, but the easier would be to bootstrap the whole thing and compute the difference between corresponding coefficients in each resample. You should find that you will fail to find a significant difference between corresponding coefficients. They are different in this sample likely solely due to sampling error.

Comment: Big picture: In the population we know how true models operate. When non-huge samples your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition and a sanity check would quickly show that it is not the case that "collapsing adjacent categories will not change the slope". If this were the case you could reduce all cumulative link models into a simple binary model. Then using logistic or probit modeling would give the result.

In your example, draw your attention to threshold coefficients:

```
Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
0|1    0.926      0.330    2.80
1|2    2.560      0.362    7.07
```

versus

```
Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2    2.117      0.452    4.69
```

Note that 2.117 seems like a weighted mean of 0.926 and 2.56. In fact it is, this is not an accident. Using a single threshold coefficient for both lower categories assigns a much higher influence to improbable observations in the lowest response level. Depending on the true relationship with time, this is a kind of model misspecification that can increase the variance of the estimates - so we can't say anything general about the direction of the result except it's even more of a cointoss so to speak.

Comment: Thank you for your response and comment. Yes, I had the same thought regarding collapsing adjacent categories, as finally it would result in a binary model, which would not be meaningful.

Comment: However, I'm still struggling to interpret the statement from article by C. Greenwood and V. Farewell (1988): "Income, for instance, may be categorized as 0-10,000, 10,000-20,000, etc., but the underlying variable is continuous. Due to this, model (1), [refers to McCullagh's PO model], exhibits a property of invariance that both Fienberg's [refers to the continuation ratio model] and Anderson's models lack. If two adjacent response categories are combined, the parameter estimates β should remain essentially unchanged. The cut points θ_j may change, but the model itself remains identical."